# Hyper-sphere packing in dimension 9

Tags: packing-problem

What is the best known lattice for sphere packing in dimension 9? The 'best' lattice is still unknown in dimension $d>8$ (except for the famous d=24!)

Comment: http://www.math.rwth-aachen.de/~Gabriele.Nebe/LATTICES/density.html

Comment: I see. Table 1.2 in the first chapter of SPLAG does also mention a $P_{9a}$ non-lattice packing. It has a higher (maximum) kissing number than $\Lambda_9$ but not as good density. So Nebe's table does not mention it, although non-lattice packings are mentioned for dimensions 10,11,13,..

Comment: similar on page 3 of Sloane: https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0207256.pdf  note that Sloane and Nebe are joint administrators of the lattice index...